# How to get saturation in a unsaturated model MODFLOW-USG?

Tags: flopy

I'm a beginner in FloPy and I'm working with a unsatured model in MODFLOW-USG (using Richards equation), and I have the output files (.hds, .ddn, .cbb). I need to export saturation of unsatured cells (a parameter between 0 and 1) but I can't find how to do it. I've seen in some papers the parameter 'water content', 'water saturation', 'saturation' but I don't know how to get it...

I've been trying to get Saturation from output file .DDN postprocessing it in FloPy with the code:

`flopy.utils.binaryfile.HeadFile(f"DRPA_TR_oc_.ddn",text="SATURATIONU", precision="auto")`

and

`flopy.utils.binaryfile.HeadFile(f"DRPA_TR_oc_.ddn",text="SATURATION", precision="auto")`

but after ~1 hour computing following appears:

```
File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flopy\utils\binaryfile.py", line 369, in _get_header
    return header[0]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

when I ran CellBudgetFile with .cbb or HeadUFile with .hds it took few minutes. So, I don't understand very well where is the error and how to fix it, and why to compute .ddn file take a lot of time.

I hope you can help me to fix the error or another way to get saturation (maybe from .hds, or whatever)  :)
I remain attentive to your comments!
Thanks in advance :)